# Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control deploy'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openshift

I am planning to deploy my developed ruby on rails 3 mysql application on openshift.

1. I have created an openshift application, by clicking add application... button
2. Entered the name of the application and the name space and choose mysql 5.1 as the database,then left that git hub sssh url as it is and then clicked create application
3. Upon successful creation I got a git clone ssh url for cloning this openshift application in to my local hard drive. I just cloned it and replaced the content of openshift with my existing rails application source code.
4. When I tried to push this change to openshift I am getting the following error. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Varun-Krishna-P/3f2eac76b7f8819b8aa6) that shows the error

Why am I getting this **Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control deploy'** How do I fix this error here ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your application log files?

Comment: I fixed it. I was doing things wrongly so I got this error.

Comment: @user3239866 it could be nice if you shared the details of the solution

Comment: @user3239866 Also having the same problem, could you please describe your solution (preferably as an answer to this question)?

Comment: Downvoting, you should share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this when I added

```
spring.profiles.active=openshift
```

to my JAVA_OPTS_EXT in env. I changed this to

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=openshift
```

In my case this was a environment fix. And this could vary in different scenarios, it looks like we get this ERROR after succesful compilation and server is about to start.